# Remove v-stepper-header number using Vuetify

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

I search everywhere trying resolve this problem and didn't find any solution. There is any way to remove the numbers from the `v-steppper-header` ?
- Vuetify version: 1.5.6

Current:
[image]

Exptected:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the `step` prop to empty string `""` as follows :

```
  <v-stepper-step :complete="e1 > 1" step="" complete>Name of step 1</v-stepper-step>
```

Comment: Thank you! It was also explained in vuetify docs, didn't notice it 

Comment: Using this approach means the content for the steps will not be shown since it is matched to the step number

Comment: @Anjayluh could you please suggest a best approach?

Comment: i'm providing an answer to the OP use case, if you need another behavior you could post a question because down-voting and not suggesting another approach doesn't make sense

Answer (score 0):

The solution above will cause problems for active/inactive classes and step identification. The less problematic solution I found today is below

> .your-stepper-selector ::v-deep .v-stepper__step__step{
> font-size: 0
> }

Answer (score 0):

I have found a temporary way to handle this stuation. It is not ideal but it gives the desired result as of now. And this is by giving the font a transparent color so it takes up the background color. This leaves the step functionality on without displaying the step number

```
.v-stepper__step--active:not(.v-stepper__step--complete) .v-stepper__step__step {
    color: transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.theme--light.v-stepper .v-stepper__step:not(.v-stepper__step--active):not(.v-stepper__step--complete):not(.v-stepper__step--error) .v-stepper__step__step {
    display: none;
}
```